# Unknown Option "noabbrev" for the package cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

In the [`cleveref` package document](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), it is clearly stated that the `noabbrev` option prevents the names of the references to be abbreviated. For instance instead of "Fig. 1", I'll get "Figure 1". However, when I use the option like this:

```
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown option 'noabbrev' for package 'cleveref'.
```

How can I solve the problem? Is there any versioning issue? I am using MacTeX-2011.

**Edit:** Here is the lines from log file related to the problem:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty
Package: cleveref 2011/03/22 v0.17.9 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `hyperref' support loaded on input line 2157.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cref on input line 2157.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cref on input line 2157.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \crefrange on input line 2157.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Crefrange on input line 2157.
...
```

Comment: Please indicate which version of `cleveref` is used by your TeX distribution. You can find this information by searching the `.log` file for the line that mentions that the `cleveref` package is being loaded. In all likelihood, your TeX distribution contains an obsolete version of the package.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, that's a useful point. See my edit, please.

Comment: Thanks buddies, I just updated the package and it works now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cleveref` is at version 0.18.4 at the moment. The `noabbrev` option was introduced in version 0.18 (from December 2011, [announcement at comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/be51380fed622fd5/364f46453960db80)), so this is most likely a versioning issue.

EDIT: According to your log file, you are using `cleveref` 0.17.9, so you need to switch to a more recent version.